# double pointer and const in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I used a function called 'calcHist' in opencv. And its declaration is:

```
void calcHist(const Mat* arrays, int narrays, const int* channels, InputArray mask, OutputArray hist, int dims, const int* histSize, const float** ranges, bool uniform=true, bool accumulate=false )
```

I wrote a code snippets:

```
Mat img = imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

Mat* arrays = &img;
int narrays = 1;
int channels[] = { 0 };
InputArray mask = noArray();
Mat hist;
int dims = 1;
int histSize[] = { 256 };   
float hranges[] = { 0.0, 255.0 };
float *ranges[] = { hranges };

calcHist(arrays, narrays, channels, mask, hist, dims, histSize, ranges);
```

and then got an error:IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "calcHist" matches the argument list
But if I prefix 'const' to 'float *ranges[] = {ranges};' like `const float *ranges[] = { hranges };` it's okay.

So why this 'const' is necessary and the 'const' before histSize is not.

Comment: @super_ No, u cant initialize double dimensional arrays like that.

Comment: @Ggicci: Yes, you can initialize two dimensional arrays like that.  But a two-dimensional array is not convertible to an array of pointers or a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T*` implicitly converts to `const T*`. Correspondingly, this means `T**` implicitly converts to `T*const*`. `T*const*` is not `const T**`, so this conversion doesn't work to let you make the function call.

Comment: `const T*` is better written as the equivalent `T const*`. Then it is easier to see that `T*` converts to `T const*` and `T**` converts to `T* const*`.

Comment: It seems "Effective C++" metions this concept... Thank u all!